# How to center text above a bar in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

In my (MuseScore) sheets have a lot of custom bar number indicators, like this:

[image: bar number]

which help me quickly glance over the length of the sections. The bar count can also be above a bar containing notes:

[image: bar with notes]

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this in Lilypond. I'm pretty sure this is possible but figuring out how-exactly is a bit of a pain.

When an empty-chord mark is used in a bar with notes, then the markup is displayed above the next note and not in the middle. So, as a workaround I could just use that but this is more of a challenge to understand how to use Lilypond to get what is needed.

Currently I'm trying to achieve this with Text Spanners, as I would like the number in parentheses to be centered above a bar.
All the examples override the text at the left and right edges of a spanner. I've also seen the `span-type` and `span-text` in some functions but am not sure how to use them.

I've also seen `\textSpannerUp` commands but have no idea how they are to be used.

Edit: The automatic bar numbers are positioned correctly when `\set Score.centerBarNumbers = ##t` is used. Meaning it is certainly doable.

[image: auto bar numbers]

The code is [here](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond/blob/c10a8ce2f345063884aad7f27042ec5ce48dd7c2/lily/bar-number-engraver.cc#L60) but I don't know Scheme that well. :(

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty way to do it:

```
markAtCenterAboveMeasure =
#(define-music-function (m music)
   (markup? ly:music?)
   #{
     \once\override
     Staff.MeasureCounter.text = #m
     <>\startMeasureCount
     #music
     <>\stopMeasureCount
   #})

\new DrumStaff \with {
  \consists Measure_counter_engraver
}{
  s1*7
  \markAtCenterAboveMeasure \markup\dynamic"(8)" s1
}
```

Comment: Quick and dirty does it! Edit: Any specific reason to use `\dynamic`? It seems to work just the same without both `\markup` and `\dynamic`.

Comment: Works well for blank bars but not when there are notes: https://imgur.com/a/9mcvKNE. It's fixed by having the notes afterwards in {}.

Comment: @AlenSiljak The choice for `\dynamic` was simply to mimic what your MuseScore example used. There is no real additional reason. About your second point: Yes, as with any music function you need to wrap multiple music events in a simultaneous music event. I thought this was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are indicating bar numbers, perhaps it makes sense to try something like a modification of [Measure-centered bar numbers](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/bars.html#Measure_002dcentered-bar-numbers), however this won't work for LilyPond versions earlier than v2.23.

Answer (score 0):

## Empty-Chord Marks

A simple solution for the blank bars can be the empty chord mark:

`s1 <>^\markup {(2)}` or simply `s1 <>^"(4)"`.

This is not centered above the bar, unfortunately.

The good thing with a markup is that it can be customized in detail and extracted into a function which can be included in multiple score sheets.

## Text Spanners

Using spanners, I've managed to do

```
    \override TextSpanner.text = "blah"
    \override TextSpanner.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
    \override TextSpanner.font-shape = #'upright
    \override TextSpanner.side-axis = 0
    \override TextSpanner.direction = #'CENTER

    bd4 \startTextSpan sn bd sn \stopTextSpan
```

which produces

[image: spanner]

but is not centered, although it does span the whole bar.